# Getting undefined value of objects array

Tags: javascript

Doing:

```
  const data = [{}];

  function doAddress(indirizzo) {
    indirizzo.forEach(function(item){
      var a = item[1];
      var location = item[0];
      let newObj = {};
      newObj.idValue = ids[a];
      newObj.addressValue = location;
      newObj.metalValue = metal[a];
      newObj.glassValue = glass[a];
      newObj.plasticValue = plastic[a];
      newObj.paperValue = paper[a];
      data.push(newObj);
    })
  }
```

Then trying to get the highest value of metal:

```
  const highestMetalValueObj = data.sort((a, b) => b.metalValue - a.metalValue)[0];
  console.log("address " + highestMetalValueObj.addressValue + " has the highest metal value of " + highestMetalValueObj.metalValue);
```

Console gives:

```
address undefined has the highest metal value of undefined
```

Why am I getting undefined and not accessing the values?

Console.log data gives:

```
0: {}
1: {idValue: 20, addressValue: "Corso Vittorio Emanuele, 1, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia", metalValue: 0.879, glassValue: 2.896, plasticValue: 1.365, …}
2: {idValue: 33, addressValue: "Via Giosuè Carducci, 15, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia", metalValue: 0.078, glassValue: 0.256, plasticValue: 0.098, …}
3: {idValue: 18, addressValue: "Via Castello, 5, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia", metalValue: 0.256, glassValue: 0.356, plasticValue: 0.085, …}
4: {idValue: 35, addressValue: "Via Marco Polo, 1, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia", metalValue: 0.356, glassValue: 0.156, plasticValue: 0.356, …}
5: {idValue: 26, addressValue: "Lungomare Amerigo Vespucci, 1, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia", metalValue: 0.321, glassValue: 0.085, plasticValue: 0.156, …}
```

Comment: The only object in the array doesn't have any properties... `const data = [{}];`

Comment: @CertainPerformance am I not pushing the values?

Comment: Do you ever call `doAddress`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance how do I construct each object with its own properties? Thought I was doing it right but...

Comment: Can you make a full [MCVE] in a runnable Stack Snippet so we can see the error for ourselves?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes i do call doAddress, I'm just asking in regards of the console log, the values are correct and doAddress works fine

Comment: @rob.m: you may be pushing values into the array, but you're starting off the array containing the empty object not as an empty array. Perhaps you mean to have `const data = [];`. When sorting, that empty object might be ending up as your first item.

Comment: No data. Nothing to sort.

Comment: @StackSlave updated the question with `console.log(data);` data is there indeed after push

Comment: You are `.push()`ing onto an Array that already has an empty Object on it, so it comes first in your sort. Should be `const data = [];` before the push, like `@Jacob` says.

Comment: @StackSlave yes I did notice that, I had tried const data = []; too and gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Comment: I don't see an `address` property. Your example is just bad.

Comment: @StackSlave yes corrected it. Was a type. Anyhow, problem was I was using Promise to call doAddress. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is probably not what you intended:

```
const data = [{}];
```

That is starting off the array as an array containing one object with no properties. You're pushing more items in there, but the original empty object is still going to be there. You're most likely having that come out as your top item after sorting.

Just start off your array as an empty array:

```
const data = [];
```

In addition, in your console statement you're addressing `highestMetalValueObj.address`, but your objects don't seem to have that property. You probably meant to use `highestMetalValueObj.addressValue` instead.

Comment: I have tried const data = []; and gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Comment: if I do  console.log(data); before

      const highestMetalValueObj  I get the correct values pushed as per my question example

Comment: Did you mean to do `highestMetalValueObj.addressValue` instead of `highestMetalValueObj.address`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressValue' of undefined
    at (index):273

Comment: console.log("address " + highestMetalValueObj.addressValue + " has the highest metal value of " + highestMetalValueObj.metalValue);

Comment: Are you calling your `doAddress` function before your console log statement?

Comment: oh maaaaan yes I was! doAddress is used in Promise !!

Comment: Ah, I suspected that. Console evaluation is lazy, so it may be actually showing the data at a later point in time than when the `console.log` command is run. Super confusing :D

Comment: You may also post a working example (data and code) using the Code Snippet feature Ctrl+m to improve the quality of questions and answers. :)